# Combobox - Filter list based on input text

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to modify the following code to allow for a combobox where the list is automatically filtered based on your input, similar to how a filter preview narrows fields when you are filtering a table column.

The code is supposed to pull in the range A1:A791 for a list of 790 items I want included in the combobox dropdown. Originally, the filter worked when I defined a static array as follows:

```
Sub ComboBox1_Populate(Optional fltr As String)
ComboBox1.List = Filter(Array("qqq", "qqwww", "qqttt", "qwer"), fltr)     
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal 
Shift As Integer)
Call ComboBox1_Populate(ComboBox1.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Call ComboBox1_Populate
End Sub
```

However, when I instead try to filter the range values as follows, I receive a Type Mismatch runtime error 13 with the following:

```
Sub ComboBox1_Populate(Optional fltr As String)
ComboBox1.List = Filter(Sheets("DVTest").Cells(2, 1).Resize(790, 10).Value, 
fltr)
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal 
Shift As Integer)
Call ComboBox1_Populate(ComboBox1.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Call ComboBox1_Populate
End Sub
```

I am looking for advice on how I can get the same filtering capability in the combobox list based on the specified range, as opposed to the static array of 4 text options.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation on the [Filter Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filter-function?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008912)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue), the `sourcearray` is a one-dimensional array of strings.

- You are clearly specifying a multi-dimensional array with `Resize(790, 10)`.
- And `.Value` returns an array of variants, not strings.

---

Upon review, an array or variants is OK, but it has to be one-dimensional; so you'll have to process the range, since even 1 column will result in a 2 dimensional array.  Here is what I would use to bridge the gap...

```
Function RangeToOneDemensionalArray(Target As Range) As Variant
Dim Cell As Range
Dim ResultArr
Dim i As Long

    If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    ReDim ResultArr(Target.Count - 1) As String

    For Each Cell In Target
        ResultArr(i) = Cell.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next

    RangeToOneDemensionalArray = ResultArr
End Function
```